# pytables 3.0 cant find hdf 1.8.12 after homebrew update and wont revert to 1.8.11

Tags: homebrew, pytables

I have a weird problem. I updated my hdf version via homebrew from 1.8.11 to 1.8.12. Of course pytables got mad cause it was build against 1.8.11 so I re-installed via pip. But now pytables complains that the headers are 1.8.11 and the library 1.8.12. I uninstalled everything (hdf5 1.8.11, 1.8.12, and pytables) and started from scratch, i.e. brew install hdf5, pip install --user tables. But I am still getting the same error:

```
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.8.11, library is 1.8.12
```

I also tried downgrading to 1.8.11, but than I ran into this error.

```
i3-dhcp-172-16-223-173:Formula xxxx$ brew versions hdf5
Warning: brew-versions is unsupported and may be removed soon.
Please use the homebrew-versions tap instead:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions
1.8.12   git checkout e54b6a9 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.11   git checkout 6e496de /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.10-patch1 git checkout 41a7410 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1        git checkout 569ea5a /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.9    git checkout 9c9cc31 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.8    git checkout 723160f /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.7    git checkout a63ba22 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.6    git checkout 6e42249 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.5-patch1 git checkout cf4aee1 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.5    git checkout 5453131 /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.4-patch1 git checkout df3114b /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
1.8.4    git checkout 10435eb /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
i3-dhcp-172-16-223-173:Formula xxxxx$ git checkout 6e496de /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb
error: pathspec '6e496de' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '../Taps/homebrew-science/hdf5.rb' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options:

1. Install HDF5 1.8.12 from brew and then install PyTables from source (not pip)
2. Be OK with the version mismatch warning.  (This difference it probably OK)

Anything else likely won't work or will cause you to run into errors.

Comment: It crashes on me else I wouldnt really care about the mismatch warning

Comment: Then I think that you are going to need to recompile PyTables. Sorry.

Comment: I altered the 1.8.12 homebrew forumla to download 1.8.11 and all is fine now